# Determining sequence of multiple streams output from FFMPEG to pipe

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently running ffmpeg, taking a video as input and by way of a complex filter:

- Splitting it into multiple streams
- For each stream, apply a set of filters (each filter performs a different transform)

After that, I map each of the streams to output a sequence of PNG images.

Currently, I'm writing everything to `pipe:1` (`stdout`) so that the program that launches ffmpeg can process the output.

Each of the streams has a need to be processed separately in the calling program.

As a result, I want to tag the PNGs with something to identify how they should be processed (so that I may sequence them properly in the merged output stream).  The `tEXt` chunk type in PNGs would be perfect for this.

The question is, how can I have ffmpeg encode that chunk (or some other piece of metadata) into the PNG?

Currently, I am trying the following:

```
ffmpeg \
    -ss <start time, put before input to seek by keyframes> \
    -to <end time> \
    -i <input, this is downloaded from an HTTPS URL> \
    -filter_complex \
        split=2[in1][in2];[in1]<some filter>[out1];[in2]<some other filter>[out2] \
    -map [out1] -metadata title=<tag1> -codec png -f image2pipe pipe:1 \
    -map [out2] -metadata title=<tag2> -codec png -f image2pipe pipe:1
```

But it doesn't create any additional chunks in the PNGs that are streamed to the pipe.

I've also tried the `metadata` filter, like so:

```
ffmpeg \
    -ss <start time, put before input to seek by keyframes> \
    -to <end time> \
    -i <input> \
    -filter_complex \
        split=2[in1][in2];[in1]<some filter>,metadata=add:key=mykey:value=mytag1[out1];[in2]<some other filter>,metadata=add:key=mykey:value=mytag2[out2] \
    -map [out1] -metadata title=<tag1> -codec png -f image2pipe pipe:1 \
    -map [out2] -metadata title=<tag2> -codec png -f image2pipe pipe:1
```

But that doesn't produce any additional metadata in the PNG stream.

Is this possible, or do I have to find another way to somehow separate the streams and process them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interleave them

```
ffmpeg \
    -i <input> \
    -filter_complex \
        split=2[in1][in2];[in1]<some filter>[out1];[in2]<some other filter>[out2]; \
       [out1][out2]interleave,setpts=N/25/TB[out] \
    -map [out] -r 25 -codec png -f image2pipe pipe:1
```

This will have one frame of out1 followed by out2 then out1...etc

Comment: Thanks for this!  I ran the command, but I seem to get the first frame repeated (across the streams) ad-infinitum.  I suspect this part of the documentation is critical: `Input streams must have well defined, monotonically increasing frame timestamp values.` I am downloading this from a URL served up via HTTPS, as well as with an input time to seek to, so not sure if this is playing a part or not.  Would welcome any suggestions.  I've updated the question appropriately to reflect this.

Comment: What are the filters you're applying.

Comment: `crop`, `scale`, `crop` (again), and possibly `hflip`.

Comment: Edited command.

Comment: FFmpeg png encoder currently does not support tEXt chunk.

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction (thank you, btw).  And I see the trick of synthesizing the framerate.  The output *looks* correct, but there's something I can't seem to figure out.  My example outputs 9940 frames, while yours outputs 4971 (this *2 is 9942, which is closer); this suggests something is being lost.  I thought it might be the frame rate (the original is 59.94 fps), so trying with 59.94 fps, I get 4972 frames (same with 60); I'm concerned about the extra frame (stream 1 has one more frame) as well.

Comment: Also, does this mean I'd have to find the fps of the original video as well (I have this value before it's called, so that's not as much of an issue).

Comment: Should also note that the clip I'm processing is 82.903 seconds long at 59.94 fps: 82.903 * 59.94 * 2 = 9938.41164 which matches very closely with the 9940 frames I was initially exporting.

Comment: Edited command.

Comment: Curious, is there a significance to setting the FPS to 25?  I have the FPS (59.94) so I can sub these values out, or does it not matter because they are the same when output from the complex filter and when setting the rate when mapping the output?  (also, thanks!)

Comment: As long as the rate used in setpts and -r is the same, it doesn't matter. Since you're outputting to an image format, the actual rate is moot. I assume you do any timekeeping by counting frames.